# Using both "ne ... que" and "seulement"

Tags: sens, négation

> En France, les amateurs d'astronomie **n**'auront **seulement** droit **qu**'à une éclipse partielle juste avant le coucher du soleil.

How does the nearly complete overlap between the two restrictive expressions "ne ... que" and "seulement" affect the meaning of the sentence? Is it for emphasis?

> vs: En France, les amateurs d'astronomie **n**'auront droit **qu**'à une éclipse partielle juste avant le coucher du soleil.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is for emphasis. Both sentences have the same meaning.

Answer (score 1):

No, "n'auront seulement droit qu'à" is not emphasis, it is incorrect. Children sometimes make that mistake. The only correct forms are:

> En France, les amateurs d'astronomie **n**'auront droit **qu**'à une éclipse partielle juste avant le coucher du soleil.

and

> En France, les amateurs d'astronomie auront **seulement** droit à une éclipse partielle juste avant le coucher du soleil.